# Why is datetime saving previous day value, in django

Tags: django, datetime, timezone

I am saving the date in python:

```
start_datetime = "24-08-2014,2.00"
start_datetime = datetime.strptime(start_datetime, '%d-%m-%Y,%H.%M')
```

It is saving previous day value and time value is wrong too, as when i try to retrieve it says:

```
print start_datetime
datetime.datetime(2014, 8, 23, 20, 30, tzinfo=<UTC>)
```

What can be the issue.

Thanks,

Comment: You haven't given nearly enough information. Where is this code, *exactly*?

Comment: Daniel please let me know what other part of the code s needed.

Comment: Check your system time as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `timezone` util

```
from django.utils import timezone
current_date = timezone.now()
```